# Creating a pulsating circle

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation

[I found a jsfiddle with a working pulsating circle (jQuery 1.8.5 edge)](http://jsfiddle.net/Y3r36/9/)

My code is excactly the same.

```
function addCircle() {
        //var rad = $(window).width();
        var $circle = $('<div class="circle"></div>');
        $circle.animate({
            'width': '300px',
            'height': '300px',
            'margin-top': '-150px',
            'margin-left': '-150px',
            'opacity': '0'
        }, 4000, 'easeOutCirc');
        $('body').append($circle);

        setTimeout(function __remove() {
            $circle.remove();
        }, 4000);
    }
    addCircle();
    setInterval(addCircle, 1200);
```

It does not work with jQuery 1.11.x
The console error is simply:

> jquery.min.js:4 Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function

[The same jsfiddle with the latest jquery (1.11.0)](http://jsfiddle.net/j5zqzpzb/)

What do I have to change? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to add jQuery UI or a [easing library](http://gsgd.co.uk/sandbox/jquery/easing/) that supports `easeOutCirc`, jQuery doesn't natively support that easing

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/j5zqzpzb/2/)